# What is the difference between using Str.c_str() directly and use it to initialize a const char *?

Tags: c++, string, winsock

I am using the winsock function `inet_addr()` to transfer IP address form string type to u_int type.

I use a `std::string` to store the user's input.

However,if I use `inet_addr(str.c_str());`  I will get the wrong output,while if I use a const char * temp before it ,like

```
    const char * temp = str.c_str();
    ip_ptr->dst.s_addr = inet_addr(temp);
```

I can get the right output,and I cannot figure out why.
What is the differece between the two?

```
    bool fliter_ip(in_addr addr,char * target ){
{
    char c[15] = { NULL };
    memcpy(c, inet_ntoa(addr), 15);
    char d[15] = { NULL };
    memcpy(d, target, 15);

    if (memcmp(c, d, 15) == 0)
        return TRUE;
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

}

This is my code.
I pass a str.c_str() as the char to this function.And the return value is different.

Comment: Showing more of your code would probably help.

Comment: Post more contextual source codes including how to check if the output is right or not.

Comment: To answer directly: There shouldn´t be a difference.

Comment: You probably have undefined behavior in some code you aren't showing us.

Comment: Sorry,acually I am using a function to compare IP address.

Comment: You can't even call that function the way you claim you are, because of the `const` mismatch.

Comment: `inet_addr` requires a nul-terminated string. Are sure that the input parameters have only 15 characters to copy, including a terminating NUL?

Comment: @BenVoigt: there is no mismatch. `inet_addr()` takes a *const* `char*` as input.  Passing `str.c_str()` directly works just fine.

Comment: @Remy: You can't pass a **`const`** `char*` as the actual argument when the formal type is `char*`, as it is in `fliter_ip`.

Comment: I did not say `std.c_str()` can be passed to `filter_ip()`, I said it can be passed to `inet_addr()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your string is actually shorter than 14 characters (+1 for null terminator), you cause undefined behaviour by `memcpy`ing 15 characters.

There is no difference at all between the first two code example; if the program appears to behave different then your program has already caused undefined behaviour earlier, and you are now seeing follow-on effects from it.

However I'm not sure why you initially say that the problem is with `inet_addr(str.c_str());`, but then you go on to post `fliter_ip`'s code instead.

Note that your function could (and should) be replaced with:

```
bool fliter_ip(in_addr addr,char const *target )
{
     return ! strcmp( inet_ntoa(addr), target );
}
```

To get more accurate help with your problem, try to produce a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

> if I use inet_addr(str.c_str()); I will get the wrong output,while if I use a const char * temp before it , ... I can get the right output

Passing `str.c_str()` directly to `inet_addr()` works just fine, so the ONLY way it would fail is if the `str` does not contain a valid IP address to begin with.  For instance, since you are getting the value from the user, make sure there are no whitespace or line break characters in it.  `inet_addr()` does not care where the `char*` comes from, just as long as it points at valid memory and is null terminated, and `str.c_str()` ensures both.